# Matching Woocommerce product status to custom field

Tags: php, woocommerce, acfpro

I am trying to set product status to draft/publish depending on the value of a custom field.
for example CF = Blank then draft, CF = draft them draft, CF = publish then publish

This has gotten me fairly close though its breaking other parts of Wordpress.

```
function change_post_status_based_on_custom_field( $post_id ) {
// If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
return;

    // Get field value
    $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'hide_product', true );
    
    $status = $value ? 'publish' : 'draft';
    
    // If status should be different, change it
    if ( get_post_status( $post_id ) != $status ) {
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );
    
        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => $status
        ) );
    
        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post_product', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );
```

Comment: Shouldnt this be `remove_action( 'save_post_product', ...)` you're missing the `_product`

Comment: Cheers @Moshe Gross - I was having a blind moment.  
Still not doing exactly what I want but a lot closer now.